# How to reference WSDL from Visual Studio folder when I am trying to add a Service Reference?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a WSDL file uploaded to folder in Visual Studio like below -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9hRh.png

How to I add this WSDL file when adding a Web Service reference?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihpDP.png

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference by passing `?wsdl` at the end in your web service base url.

Refer these [steps to reference web service](http://reference1.mapinfo.com/software/spectrum/lim/8_0/developerguide/Spatial/source/Development/gettingstarted/accessing/csharp.html) with wsdl or [consuming rest api from .NET application](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications) for more information.